# How can I test index.js which uses react-redux connect and export exports items

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, react-redux, jestjs

So I have this index.js file which exports some function using react-redux connect function, I am trying to test this index.js file but unable to successfully test it, be great if someone could help, thanks

```
index.js 

import { connect } from "react-redux";
import HomePageDetails from "./HomePageDetails";
import * as actions from "../../../actions";
import { getLink, getTitle } from "../../../selectors";

export default connect(
  (state) => ({
    title: getTitle(state),
    link: getLink(state)
  }),
  actions
)(HomePageDetails);
```

Need to test index.js that it exports connect with title and link, I have tried below
But I get error below

[image]

```
import { connect } from "./index";

describe("RolePresetDetails index.js", () => {
  let getPageTitleMock;
  let getLabelsMock;

  beforeEach(() => {
    getPageTitleMock = jest.fn();
    getLabelsMock = jest.fn();
  });

  it("exports pageTitle", () => {
    const connectMock = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({
      pageTitle: getPageTitleMock,
      getLabel: getPageTitleMock
    });

    expect(connect()).toEqual();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point of testing this file is to see if the component being connected is getting the correct state slice through the selectors, and if the action can be triggered correctly, which is its behavior. There is no point in just mocking `connect` and checking to see if it was called.

A simple mock `HomePageDetails` component can be provided to avoid overly complex implementation logic for the original component and dependencies on too many other modules that don't have much to do with testing this file. And provide a mock store to check if the event handler is dispatching action correctly.

E.g.

`index.js`:

```js
import HomePageDetails from './HomePageDetails';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from './actions';
import { getLink, getTitle } from './selectors';

export default connect(
  (state) => ({
    title: getTitle(state),
    link: getLink(state),
  }),
  actions
)(HomePageDetails);
```

`HomePageDetails.jsx`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class HomePageDetails extends Component {
  render() {
    return <div>HomePageDetails</div>;
  }
}
```

`selectors.js`:

```js
export const getTitle = (state) => state.title;
export const getLink = (state) => state.link;
```

`actions.js`:

```js
export const getData = () => ({ type: 'GET_DATA' });
```

`index.test.js`:

```js
import ConnectedHomePageDetails from './';
import React from 'react';
import { render, unmountComponentAtNode } from 'react-dom';
import { act } from 'react-dom/test-utils';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import createMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';

const mockStore = createMockStore();

jest.mock('./HomePageDetails', () => {
  function MockedHomePageDetails(props) {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>mocked home page details</h1>
        <p data-testid="title">title: {props.title}</p>
        <p data-testid="link">link: {props.link}</p>
        <button data-testid="btn" onClick={() => props.getData()}>
          get data
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
  return MockedHomePageDetails;
});

describe('68733914', () => {
  let container = null;
  beforeEach(() => {
    container = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(container);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    unmountComponentAtNode(container);
    container.remove();
    container = null;
  });

  test('should pass', () => {
    const store = mockStore({ title: 'mocked title', link: 'mocked link' });
    act(() => {
      render(
        <Provider store={store}>
          <ConnectedHomePageDetails />
        </Provider>,
        container
      );
    });
    expect(container.querySelector("[data-testid='title']").textContent).toEqual('title: mocked title');
    expect(container.querySelector("[data-testid='link']").textContent).toEqual('link: mocked link');

    const button = container.querySelector('[data-testid=btn]');
    act(() => {
      button.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', { bubbles: true }));
    });
    expect(store.getActions()).toEqual([{ type: 'GET_DATA' }]);
  });
});
```

test result:

```
 PASS  examples/68733914/index.test.js (8.844 s)
  68733914
    ✓ should pass (34 ms)

--------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File          | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
--------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files     |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 actions.js   |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.js     |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 selectors.js |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
--------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        9.481 s
```

Comment: Thanks Mate, had to make few changes but you example helped a lot :)